# Checking for a value without an undefined error stopping execution?

Tags: jquery

When I go to check for data that I may or may NOT have set using the jQuery $.data() method, how can I check gracefully?  Meaning when my code runs below and I haven't set the data and no key exists for this yet (there are reasons I may check for this midstream in my logic), it blows up saying that $("#singleModelText").data("modelId").ModelId is undefined.

I know it's undefined but how can I just check for this and if it's not defined move on?  How can I do like a

> if(!$("#singleModelText").data("modelId").ModelId) // set it

```
modelId_label = $("#singleModelText").data("modelId").ModelId;
```

it blows up on the line above if there's no data.

Answer (score 2):

Check to see if the data exists at all first before checking its properties.

```
var myData = $("#singleModelText").data("modelId");
if(!myData || !myData.ModelId) // set it
```

Comment: but isn't that what I did in your first line above in my code?  I don't try to use the variable I just try to set it and it blows up.

Comment: You aren't checking to see if `$("#singleModelText").data("modelId")` exists before reading the ModelId property from it. Are you sure this is what you actually want to do anyway? Have you actually stored an object with the key of modelId that has a property of ModelId?

Comment: gotcha, I didn't think of that whole line as an object...thanks.  So really data("modelId") is an object...